# Why the camel-kafka consumer goes into java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException when autoCommitEnable is false?

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have two java codes to consume messages from kafka.

1. using high-level consumer API
2. camel-kafka 'from(endpoint)' syntax

When I disable autocommit in camel-kafka it run into `java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException`, why it is forcing to commit the consumer offsets before fetching next batch? where as it does not happen in high level API implementation.

Exception trace is:

```
ERROR - KafkaConsumer              - 
java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.dowait(CyclicBarrier.java:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier.await(CyclicBarrier.java:427)
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaConsumer$BatchingConsumerTask.run(KafkaConsumer.java:165)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I just want to read all messages from kafka broker without committing offset. Is there any config params need to pass in endpoint?

Comment: BTW it happens after consuming exactly 100 messages from kafka broker.

Comment: What version of Camel and Kafka Broker are you using?

Comment: Camel: 2.15.2 with Kafka 0.8.2.1, also to note it happens when i provide "autoCommitEnable" param in endpoint it will have same behavior on 'true/false' values.

Comment: I noticed the same issue. This problem aside, why would you ever not want to commit offsets?

Comment: i am load testing my consumer API and also want to commit offsets manually once message is processed and written in DB. so should not be blocked even i consume and do not commit.

Comment: I see. I don't think you can achieve that with `camel-kafka`. If I'm not mistaken, it currently uses only the High Level Consumer hence it will be impossible to "pass" any kind of offset "manually" to it.

Comment: And by reading the code  `autoCommitEnable = false` only turns your regular auto committing consumer into a batch one. It still commits automatically the offsets but it does it periodically (rather than for each message). The property name choice seems rather confusing.

Comment: yes the high level api provides self commit and not Batch commit as in camel-kafka. So Camel-Kafka need to provide this feature. "Claus Ibsen" need your input here.